# C why is the DBL_MANT_DIG macro defined as 53

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I want to know why DBL_MANT_DIG is set to 53, even though the ieee 754 standard uses 52 mantissa bits. Is it counting the sign bit as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact the binary IEEE 754 representation includes a *hidden bit*: the leading bit of the mantissa is required to be 1 for normal numbers and because of that it has not to be stored. So the mantissa is in fact that leading 1 bit plus the 52 other bits which gives... 53

References from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory) (emphasize mine):

> For numbers with an exponent in the normal range (the exponent field being neither all ones nor all zeros), the leading bit of the significand will always be 1. Consequently, a leading 1 can be implied rather than explicitly present in the memory encoding, and under the standard the explicitly represented part of the significand will lie between 0 and 1. This rule is called *leading bit convention*, *implicit bit convention*, or *hidden bit convention*. This rule allows the binary format to have **an extra bit of precision**.

Comment: *Implicit* is far better than *hidden*, I think the former to be more serious, and the latter to be misleading.